# Problem with jquery in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

i have a HTML menu. Here is code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="">
            About
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="">
            Hats
        </a>
    </li>

    <ul style="display:none">
        <li>
            <a href="">
                Big
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                Small
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="">
            Summer clothes
        </a>
    </li>
```

And here is JQuery code which shows sub menu when mouse is hover

```
$('.MenuItems ul li').hover(
    function () 
    {
        /*alert($(this).parent().children('ul').text());*/

        if($(this).parent().children('ul').children().size()>0)
        {
             $(this).parent().children('ul').show();

             $(this).parent().children('ul').hover(
                           function(){ $(this).show(); },
                           function(){ $(this).hide(); }
                           ); 
        }
    }, 

  function () 
  {
       $(this).parent().children('ul').hide();

  });
```

It's work ok in all browser except ie7.  $(this).parent().children('ul') return 0 children in ie7 and 2 childrent in any other browser. What is the workaround?

Comment: You might want to upgrade to IE 8 or 9 ;)

Comment: Why didn't you post the part of your code that would show us what `this` is in that ".hover()" setup?  What element is it?  Also: that code looks like it keeps piling more and more handlers on to the `<ul>` element, which is a really bad idea.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry. I edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just nest the first level in a single `ul` and the submenus inside the relative `li` ..

```
<div class="MenuItems">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Hats</a>
            <ul style="display:none">
                <li><a href="">Big</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Small</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Summer clothes</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

you javascript for this html should be

```
$('.MenuItems ul li').hover(
    function() {
        var $submenu = $(this).children('ul');
        if ( $submenu.children('li').size() > 0) {
            $submenu.show();
        }
    },
    function() {
        var $submenu = $(this).children('ul');
        $submenu.hide();

    }
);

// submenus handling moved outside of the menu handling to avoid repeated bounding of event
$('.MenuItems li > ul').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }
);
```

You should also avoid binding events from inside other events, because that results (*unless closely monitored*) in repeated event handling.

Your code for example will bind method to the hover event each time the submenu `ul` is hovered. If you hover/unhover multiple time it will bind the event many times and will result in repeated function getting called (*degrades performance and repeats code that most likely is to be run once on hover..*)

**example at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4N2Gj/1/

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings)?

```
$(this).siblings('ul').hide();
```

Other recommended code cleanup:

```
function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $sibs = $this.siblings('ul');
    if ($sibs.children().length) {
        $sibs.show();
        $sibs.hover(
           function() {
            $(this).show();
        }, function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }
},

function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul').hide();
});
```

Comment: Wow, never knew about that function. Will come in handy for sure!